# Convert Zero Datetime vs Allow Zero Datetime

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, datetime

`Convert Zero Datetime=true` returns **DateTime.MinValue** while `Allow Zero Datetime` return **MySqlDateTime**.

What else differentiate these 2 settings ?
When to use which one?
Can they be used interchangeable ?
What is pro and cons of them ?

Comment: How about you take every possible effort to avoid zero dates? A zero date is *not* a NULL, it's an invalid value. It means the original data was lost. DateTime.MinValue on the other hand is perferctly valid. Inserting invalid dates should fail, not return magic numbers. You should probably handle this error value in the query itself, where you have some idea what produced it. I'd prefer to have *both* of these set to false, so I get an error if a query ever returned an error date.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to this point for a little clarification: http://forums.devart.com/viewtopic.php?t=21367

But it all boils down to how you want to handle zero values on DateTime, When you use Allow Zero DateTime it cannot be converted to a DateTime because it doesn't support zero value. If you use Convert Zero DateTime it will use DateTime but it will return the lower value possible for date which is DateTime.MinValue.

Comment: This isn't a NULL value, it's an error value. From the docs, `Invalid DATE, DATETIME, or TIMESTAMP values are converted to the “zero” value of the appropriate type ('0000-00-00' or '0000-00-00 00:00:00').`. NULLs are perfectly valid though and so is DateTime.MinValue. The very existence of a Zero DateTime is problemeatic and should be avoided eg with input validation or filtering out invalid values when querying. If it *has* to be returned*, it shouldn't be converted to a valid value

Comment: Yeah, I wrote null carelessly, I edited it out. Anyhow null is not valid for DateTime on c# for it's a struct.

Comment: The sane option would be to set both options to FALSE and clean up the errors when they appear. Not allow error values to propagate. If the error is caused by bad input data, *don't* store them. If it's produced by a bad formula, *don't* just cover it up.

Comment: it's not about C#. There is no zero date. Definitely not on the Gregorian calendar used by DateTime. I'm not sure if *any* calendar has a zero date. MySQL's zero date is an error value and shouldn't even appear in data query results.